# PHP - How to read up to EOF - socket resource?

Tags: php, sockets

I want to read socket resource up to end of file.

```
$socket = fsockopen($ip,3083);
fwrite($fh,fread($socket,800));
```

How to implement EOF instead of some specific number like 800.

Comment: Have you tried `fwrite($fh, fread($socket, filelength($socket));` ? I am not sure if it works for sockets the same way as normal files, but you could try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
while( !feof( $socket ) ) {
 fwrite( $fh, fread( $socket, 800 ) );
}
```

should do the job.
cf. [feof()](http://php.net/feof)

Comment: well, it is implemented that way, even in the underlying C-function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/

Comment: It must be noted that `fread` will try to read 800 bytes even when there's less than 800 bytes to be read. That may hang your script until fread timeouts while waiting to receive more bytes that the resource can actually deliver.